# I want to escape all characters within square brackets except start and end of that bracket in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

Input:

```
[cd ab:12:00][abc-12][abc.c 12][abc]
```

Desired Output:

```
[][][][]
```

Comment: What do you mean by escape? This `re.sub(r'\[[^\]]*\]', r'[]', s)` gives the output you expected.

Comment: That looks like you're just removing them, not escaping them.

Comment: hi avinash i want to know how it is working ?@AvinashRaj

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through `re.sub` function.

```
>>> s = '[cd ab:12:00][abc-12][abc.c 12][abc]'
>>> re.sub(r'\[[^\]]*\]', r'[]', s)
'[][][][]'
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `\[` matches the literal `[` symbol.
- `[^\]]*` negated character class which matches any character but not of `]`, zero or more times. So this matches all the chars present in-between two square brackets.
- `\]` matches the literal `]` bracket. So this regex would match all the square brackets block. Replacing all the matched blocks with `[]` will give you the desired output of removing all the chars present inside the square brackets.

You could achieve the same by using lookaround assertions.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=\])', r'', s)
'[][][][]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[^\[\]]+`

Match all except `[` and `]`. You can replace matches with `""`

Ex:

```
re.sub(r'[^\[\]]+', r'', str);
```

Comment: what if i want [][abc-12][][abc] ?

Comment: i want this  [][abc-12][][abc] as o/p ?

Comment: is it random? or you want to capture specific tokens?

Comment: i want to capture specific tokens

Comment: can you give examples? or the tokens are always `abc-12` and `abc`?

Comment: [][abc-1][abc][xyz][][].... first and last brackets will be empty always but 2nd ,3rd and 4th will be changing......

Comment: So, you just want to make 1st and last brackets empty?